# Ubuntu 20.04. Wifi TPLink extender issue

Tags: wireless, tp-link

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 20.04. I can connect to my main WIFI signal, but cannot connect to TP Link WiFi extender. The same laptop with Windows 10 (dual boot) works fine.
Other devices like tablets, ipads or phones are connected to this extender normally. Only in Ubuntu 20.04 is the problem.
Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: I had many issues connecting Ubuntu 20.04 to TP-Link devices. The only way I could fix it was by updating my kernel to 5.6. Now everything is working fine.

Comment: Do you have WPA2/AES enabled for the wireless network in your TP-Link, and in your router? Do you have `wpasupplicant` installed in Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm new in GNU/Linux, I've a WPA2/AES password in my main router and other in my TPlink extender (the extender have other network name). I don't know what is wpasupplicant. I just installed ubuntu 20.04 and its updates via software updates panel.

Comment: I've updated to kernel 5.6.14 and the problem was not fixed.

Comment: I am sad to hear that updating your kernel did not fix the problem. Would you mind describing in more details what kind of error you experience when you try to connect to the TP Link WiFi Extender?

Comment: I'll try to be clear in my description....I see the TPLink extender Signal on my Networks, I connect with this network, but the network can't connecto to internet...at the same time other devices like phones or TV are connected without problems. The same laptop with windows works fine, the issue is only with ubuntu. The problem is only with TPlink extender, I can connect fine to my main WiFi signal.

Answer (score 9):

Today I faced a similar problem after switching over to Linux from Windows 10. Windows, my phone, consoles, etc were all able to connect to my TP-Link extender, but my Linux installation couldn't. I found your thread and was dismayed to find it had no solution, but as I managed to fix the problem for myself, I thought I'd post what worked for me here.

After a while of searching, I decided to try changing the DHCP client. I installed the package `dhcpcd5` ([ref](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/dhcpcd5_7.1.0-2build1_amd64.deb.html)) from the repositories and then used a text editor to open the file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.

Underneath the header `[main]`, I added the line `dhcp=dhcpd`.

I ran `sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service`, then `sudo systemctl start NetworkManager.service`. I was then able to connect, and a speed test indicates the WiFi network is working properly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: works for my TP-Link RE650. The package is called `dhcpcd5`. See here: https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/dhcpcd5_6.11.5-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb.html

Install goes with `sudo apt install dhcpcd5`

Comment: It actually did work for me, too. After those changes and a restart, I was able to connect to my repeater (TP-Link RE365) and did get a IPv4 address. But I still don't like the idea to have to install a new DHCP client after a fresh ubuntu installation. Does no one have an idea, why ubuntu fails to connect to a repeater?

Comment: Also worked for TP-Link TL-WR841N.

Comment: I needed to disable IPv4 method in wifi settings gui. Then it worked.

Answer (score 4):

I also faced the same problem. I checked /var/log/syslog and found there a suspicious warning dhcp4 (...): request timed out. So I tried the suggestion to add to /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf the line dhcp=dhcpcd and it didn't work for me. But adding instead dhcp=dhclient did work.

Comment: Yes, i also had the same problem and also the same request timed out in logs. This worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Same here. It works like a charm!

Comment: Thank you @uf-fish, it helped me a lot on my Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. So the process is in terminal: `sudo apt install dhcpcd5`,`sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, under main section added line `dhcp=dhcpcd`, save the file with `CTRL+X` and `ENTER`, run in terminal `sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service && sudo systemctl start NetworkManager.service`, retry to connect.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem. In my case, the previous solution didn't work (installing `dhcpd5` and adding the line in `NetworkManager.conf`).

On top of that, I did apply the steps suggested in this [link](https://community.tp-link.com/en/home/forum/topic/208022) (which ironically seems to get info from AskUbuntu) and that worked. I copy the steps here just in case they help somebody else:

```
git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu.git
cd rtl88x2bu
VER=$(sed -n 's/\PACKAGE_VERSION="\(.*\)"/\1/p' dkms.conf)
sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks bimblesticks, the solution outlined by you works for me with Comfast wifi extender. I had restart the system to get working. And you have `dhcpd` in your comment that need to be replaced with `dhcpcd` as package name is dhcpcd5.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to leave this as a comment on @bimblesticks answer but I don't have the necessary reputation.

Device is a TPLINK RE300, Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, Kernel: Linux 5.17.0-1020-oem

When I had the question mark symbol, the results of ifconfig showed that I was getting assigned inet6 entries but no inet4.

After running `sudo apt install dhcpd5` and restarting my machine, the question mark symbol was gone, and running ifconfig now showed both inet4 and inet6 entries.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My God, I wasted so much time trying to fix this from the linux side. I had the same issue, and here's what solved it for me, in case it helps anybody else (I have a TP-Link RE550):

- Use the Tether app to connect to the TP-Link device
- Go to `Tools` > `DHCP Settings`
- Change `Auto` to `Enable`
- Tap `SAVE`

For whatever reason I had to change the start of the IP Address Pool to `192.168.1.180`, because `192.168.1.200` is "Invalid format".

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Terminal:

   sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
2. Add `dhcp=dhclient` like mentioned below

   ```
   [main]
   dhcp=dhclient
   plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

   [ifupdown]
   managed=false

   [device]
   wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
   ```

3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to save the file
4. `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`

now connect the wifi it will connect!!!

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this issue with router TP-Link Archer C24:

1. check if you have ping to 1.1.1.1
2. if yes - go to the router settings

   1. List item Network->DHCP server and change DHCP servers to 1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8
3. reboot the router and test

Original solution: https://community.tp-link.com/en/home/forum/topic/267194

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution in the last two weeks for my Netgear AC750 repeater (EX3110) under Mint 21.3. I am a beginner with Linux and there was no success till now. This version works excellent for me too:

"Thank you @uf-fish, it helped me a lot on my Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. So the process is in terminal: sudo apt install dhcpcd5,sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf, under main section added line dhcp=dhcpcd, save the file with CTRL+X and ENTER, run in terminal sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service && sudo systemctl start NetworkManager.service, retry to connect. –
Matija
Nov 23, 2023 at 18:25 "

Many many many Thanks for the posts here and special thanks for Matija for the steps explained. It works super! It has made may Sunday very happy! :)

Best regards

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1341542)